# Capturing images with OpenCV 2.2 and Python on Linux (Fedora 15 Beta)

Tags: python, linux, opencv, webcam, fedora

I have the code below ;

```
import cv
import time

cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
    break
```

The above code is OpenCV-2.2's own CAM capture script for Python. So I know nothing is wrong with the program. And I can use my cam with different applications on Linux like the program called Cheese. However when I compile this program I get an error as below;

```
(camera:2519): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_debug_add_log_function: assertion `func != NULL' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:2521): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstbcmdec.so': /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstbcmdec.so: undefined symbol: gst_video_format_new_caps
```

I'm guessing that there is something wrong with the GStreamer. Is there a way to fix this? Or is there a problem with OpenCV-2.2 itself? Or maybe something is wrong with the sample script?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That symbol should be provided by the package gstreamer-plugins-base.

Check if you have it installed. If you do have it, it means your version of this package is  older than what OpenCV 2.2 needs. It's best to update the entire [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/) on your platform just to be sure.

Comment: I've had some problems using OpenCV and Python on version 2.1 and I don't know if they fixed it yet,  but it was related to VideoWriter. Nevertheless, the C/C++ interfaces worked wonderfully, even though  the Python interface disappointed a little bit.

Comment: It turns out that my GStreamer was out of date thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different camera index

```
capture = cv.cvCaptureFromCam(1)
```

or other higher indexes

Comment: I for one read the opencv reference and
that index should be 0 or -1 UNLESS you have more than one camera attached.